# Issue with View visibility when going back to a Fragment using back button

Tags: android, android-activity, visibility

I have a View with visibility set to `GONE` in the layout xml and that may be set to `VISIBLE` programmatically in the Fragment. When going back to this Fragment with the Back button, the View's visibility is always set to `GONE`, even if it was set to `VISIBLE` before leaving it.

How can I keep the state of my fragment (only onResume() is called when going back to the fragment)?

Thanks

**XML**

```
...
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sub_bio_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" />
....
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...
    LinearLayout sub_bio_container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sub_bio_container);

    if(<some condition>){
        sub_bio_container.setVisibility(VIEW.VISIBLE);
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: If you could post your onStart, onResume, onPause and onStop methods, it would be most helpful.

Comment: @David Burström: and where do I save the visibility state of my view?

Comment: @user370305: I added the code to my post.

Comment: Is this code in onCreate() method of activity?

Comment: It's in the `onCreateView()` method of a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Well an idea would be: set the view in xml as `VISIBLE` and when you use it in app (via inflate or by findviewbyid()) set it to `GONE`. Like this it will be visible in on resume, and you can control it's visibility from code.

A second idea would be: Keep track in on resume if the view was hidden or not, and set that view's visibility in onResume().

Answer (score 1):

use **onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)** to save your application state (e. visibility status of your views) and **onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState)** to retrieve the last state.

Comment: In the end I'm not using an Activity but a Fragment. onRestoreInstanceState() is not available for fragments.

Comment: In that case simply pass the savedInstanceState values to the constructor of your Fragment (incase you are adding fragment programetically) else you can save the saved instance in the exsistinc activity intent and in your fragent when you recieve onStart just check the data in activity intent and use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Documentation :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Depending if you are finishing your activity or not, there might be onRestart as well.

Can you show us you XML/Code ?

Answer (score -2):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            view.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE)
                    onResume();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```